# Subprocess with variables & Command from different class

Tags: python, model-view-controller, subprocess

============================================

## Fixed

**Manage to get this corrected heres the correct way of doing this for future viewers: http://pastebin.com/uM0z8Q2v**

============================================

source:
http://pastebin.com/utL7Ebeq

My thinking is that if i run from controller class "main"
it will allow me to take the "data" from Class "model", def "filename". 
It doesn't seem to work. As you can see below what i mean

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View()
    def main(self):
        data = self.model.filename()
        self.view.tcpdump(data)
class View:
    def tcpdump(self, command):
        subprocess.call(command.split(), shell=False)
```

When i run my code i get this error:

```
subprocess.call(command.split(), shell=False)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

My guess means that its not picking up command (look at source for reference) or that its not getting command with variables. But i know the error when variables are not being picked up so i don't think it is that.

My question is, from what i have thus far, how do i from "class view" grab "command" for my subprocesses to run.

Thanks~

John Riselvato

Comment: It's more proper to post that as an answer instead of inserting it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to get this corrected heres the correct way of doing this for future viewers: http://pastebin.com/uM0z8Q2v

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning anything from `filename()`.  When you don't return anything, `None` is returned instead, so the parameter `command` to `tcpdump` is `None`, which gives you the error: you can't call `split()` on the `None` object.

Change the `filename()` function in the `Model` class to return a string.

Answer (score 1):

After line 20, add:

`return self.raw`

Since you don't return anything from the function, the function returns `None` and that is why you get the error.

Comment: I don't think i am following what your saying. If i return self.raw it allows i guess for it to be carried, but if i want to return other variables it seems to skip over other parts of my script.
Still after i just do return self.raw it still shows that it is 'none'

Comment: Alright i had to fix some un-needed code and i got the return completed with 'self.raw'

I am having issues with 'input_host' and 'input_host2'
though, but i'll manage to figure it out thanks.